# this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser call returns Subscriber instead of actual object

Tags: angular

How do I get the `this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser` to return an object instead of a `Subscriber` value?

**DashboardComponent**

```
this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUserUid().then(uid => {
  if(uid) {
    this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(uid).then(user => {
      console.log(user);
    })
  }
});
```

`console.log(user)` produces the following:

[image]

**DashboardFacade**

```
getCurrentUser(uid: string): Promise<unknown> {
  return this.userService.getUser(uid);
}
```

**UserService**

```
getUser(uid: string): Promise<unknown> {
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .currentUser.getIdToken()
    .then((token: string) => {
      this.logger.debug(`Token generated: ${token}`);
      return this.httpClient
        .get(`${environment.apiBasePath}/users`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        })
        .subscribe((response) => {
          // I can get the list of users if I console log here
          return response;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, services like `UserService.getUser` are not supposed to subscribe. They should return Observable. A response from `httpClient` will be processed by someone else (DashboardComponent)

So, your problem can be resolved by removing `.subscribe` from `UserService.getUser`

```js
getUser(uid: string): Promise<unknown> {
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .currentUser.getIdToken()
    .then((token: string) => {
      this.logger.debug(`Token generated: ${token}`);
      return this.httpClient
        .get(`${environment.apiBasePath}/users`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: What would the other methods look like as a result?

Comment: UserService.getUser now returns `getUser` `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

Comment: @methuselah That's right. You can get data via subscription `getUser().subscribe(x => console.log('data from getUser', x))`